# Update wordpress post from front-end (using acf)

Tags: wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

I am making front end admin for users to add/edit their posts. I already made post add form and it works, but edit form doesnt work.

functions.php

```
function add_new_post( $post_id )
{
    if( $post_id == 'new' ) {
        // Create a new post
        $post = array(
            'post_title' => $_POST["fields"]['field_52c810cb44c7a'],
            'post_category' => array(4),
            'post_status'  => 'draft',
            'post_type'  => 'post'
        );

        // insert the post
        $post_id = wp_insert_post( $post );

        return $post_id;
    }
    else {
        return $post_id;
    }
}add_filter('acf/pre_save_post' , 'add_new_post' );
```

index.php

```
<div id="updateform-<?php the_ID(); ?>" class="collapse">
    <?php
    echo get_the_ID();
    $args = array(
        'post_id' => get_the_ID(), // post id to get field groups from and save data to
        'field_groups' => array(31), // this will find the field groups for this post (post ID's of the acf post objects)
        'form' => true, // set this to false to prevent the <form> tag from being created
        'form_attributes' => array( // attributes will be added to the form element
            'id' => 'post',
            'class' => '',
            'action' => get_permalink( get_the_ID() ),
            'method' => 'post',
        ),
        'return' => add_query_arg( 'updated', 'true', get_permalink() ), // return url
        'html_before_fields' => '', // html inside form before fields
        'html_after_fields' => '', // html inside form after fields
        'submit_value' => 'Update', // value for submit field
        'updated_message' => 'Post updated.', // default updated message. Can be false to show no message
    );
    acf_form( $args );
    ?>
</div>
```

Comment: did you ever get this working?  I am looking for a solution to this question as well.

Comment: Yes, but it was long time ago. Now ACF has built in function to output their form to frontend. Please check http://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/create-a-front-end-form/

Answer (score 1):

For saving posts you should use `save_post` not `pre_save_post`.
Basically `pre_save_post` is used for new posts.

Use this below `add_filter('save_post' , 'add_new_post');`

Answer (score 0):

I created plugins for that:

1. Forms actions
   https://wordpress.org/plugins/forms-actions/

Add actions to yours ACF forms.

2. ACF Frontend display
   https://wordpress.org/plugins/acf-frontend-display/

Display your ACF form on frontend

Answer (score 0):

If by some chance you happen to be using [Elementor Page Builder](https://wordpress.org/plugins/elementor/), you can do this by installing [Advanced Widgets for Elementor](https://wordpress.org/plugins/advanced-elementor/). It comes with an `ACF Form` widget that you can just drag & drop anywhere into your site and configure your form through the UI (no coding required).